# package.json configuration to run server and Client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, client, package.json

This is my configuration for the global package.json

```
"server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "deploy": "npm run server & npm run client",
```

when i run directly in the terminal : npm run server & npm run client it it runs correctly
but if I write: npm run deploy it runs only the server.I don't know why. please if u know guys tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem solve by using this command

```
npm server & npm client
```

Comment: I tested it and does not work

Comment: I have no idea for this issue, please give more information about package.json file

Answer (score 0):

USE Start keyword

```
{ "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",

"client": "npm run start --prefix client",

"deploy": "start npm run server & start npm run client",
}
then run command
npm run deploy
```

Comment: thanks for the information:; it was really precious .but  it solved the problem partially by opening two windows on cmd. I was wating to run the two commands on a single window  using git-bash  as a terminal .